# Eclipse subversion svn don't upload a directory

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I have a project that I need to upload to my svn server.  There is a folder/directory that I do not want to upload to the svn server every time I commit my project.
Is it possible to make it so that subversion will automatically not commit the directory, or will I have to uncheck that directory in the commit dialog every time.  The reason that I want this is so that I wont make a mistake and accidentaly commit the directory.
Thanks,
  Aidan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a [svn:ignore](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) property to the parent directory, and set its value to the name of the directory you don't want to commit. Then commit the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you need modifiable configuration directory.

The best way to do it is to copy files under source control into some temporary place and use that place as a source for your configuration.

This way SCM system will never pick up your customized environment settings.